# Load a model into an a-entity

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm attempting to do conditional loading of a model into an a-entity. The reason for this is that I've got a scene which I would like to give the user a choice to load a large model or not. So far I've got a scene with the following entity:

```
  id="modelname-entity"
  scale="2 2 2"
  position="0 0 -5"
  drag-rotate="rotateY:false;"
  model-rotate-loadprogress="modelUrl:modelname.gltf;modelRef:modelname-model"
  ></a-entity>
```

which has a component `model-rotate-loadprogress` which loads the gltf model with THREE.js syntax:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('model-rotate-loadprogress',{
      schema : {
        modelUrl: {
          type: "string"
        },
        modelRef: {
          type: "string"
        }
      },

      init : function(){

        this.loadModel();

      },

      loadModel: function() {

        if (!this.data.modelUrl || !this.data.modelRef) {
          console.warn("Model details not given for model rotate loader");
          return;
        }
        if ( document.getElementById(this.data.modelRef) ) {
            console.warn("Assets already has an asset with the ID of " , this.data.modelRef );
        }

        // Using THREE.js file loader
        var dis = this;

        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath( '/assets/static/models/' );
        loader.load(
          this.data.modelUrl,

          gltf => {
            // Add the model to the scene for now.
            dis.el.sceneEl.object3D.add(gltf.scene);
          },

          xhr => {
            console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
          },

          error => {
            console.error( error );
          }
        );
      }
  }
```

The model loads and gets displayed to the scene but how to I attach it to the entity instead?

Answer (score 1):

I got the model populating the `<a-entity>` in the similar way to how I got it attaching it to the scene. Here's the final code:

```
    loadGLTFModel: function() {

        var dis = this;
        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath( this.PATH_MODELS );

        loader.load(
          `${this.PATH_MODELS}${this.data.gltfModel}`,
          gltf => {
            dis.el.object3D.add(gltf.scene)
          },
          progress => {
            this.onProgress(progress);
          },
          error => {
            console.error( "ERROR : " , error );
          }
        );
      },
    onProgress: function(progress) {
        this.progressBar.setAttribute("geometry", {
          thetaLength: (progress.loaded / progress.total * 360)
        })
      },
```

If I were to add the heavy model to the `<a-assets>` which is the recommended way of doing things, would result in the whole application being blocked until all the assets are loaded and ready. In my scenario the user has a choice of skipping the download. If the user chooses to load the model then he/she gets a progressbar (actually a ring) which gets updated.
Here's code how to load obj and mtl models:

```
      loadOBJModel: function() {

        var dis = this;

        if (!this.data.mtlMaterial) {
          console.error("No material given for model");
          return;
        }

        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

                mtlLoader.load(
            `${this.PATH_MODELS}${this.data.mtlMaterial}`,
            materials => {

              materials.preload();
              var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( this.PATH_MODELS );
                objLoader.load(
                   this.data.objModel,
                    object => {
                                dis.el.object3D.add(object)
                   },
                   progress => {
                      this.onProgress(progress);
                   },
                   error => {
                      console.error( "ERROR : " , error );
                   }
               );
             }
          );

      },
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to invoke the GLTFLoader. Use the [gltf-model component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/gltf-model.html#sidebar):

```
loadModel: function() {

   if (!this.data.modelUrl || !this.data.modelRef) {
     console.warn("Model details not given for model rotate loader");
     return;
    }
   if ( document.getElementById(this.data.modelRef) ) {
      console.warn("Assets already has an asset with the ID of " , this.data.modelRef );
   }

   this.el.setAttribute(‘gltf-model’, ‘url(‘ + this.data.modelUrl + ‘)’);
}
```

I recommend pre loading the model in [a-assets](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/asset-management-system.html#sidebar) so user doesn’t have to wait for network. Pre load both the large and small models.